# How to remove part of string with javascript regex without repeating delimiting strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to remove an unknown substring when it occurs between two known substrings (`<foo>` and `</foo>`).  For example, I'd like to convert:

```
hello <foo>remove me</foo>
```

to:

```
hello <foo></foo>
```

I can do it with:

```
s = ...
s.replace(/<foo>.*?<\/foo>/, '<foo></foo>')
```

but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it without repeating the known substrings (`<foo>` and `</foo>`) in the regex and the replacement text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can capture tag in a `captured group` and use it later as back reference:

```
var repl = s.replace(/<(foo)>.*?<\/\1>/, '<$1></$1>');
//=> hello <foo></foo>
```

Note `\1` and `$1` are back references to the captured group #1.

[image]

Comment: just asking. will it work for `<foo><a>...</a></foo>`?

Comment: Clean and efficient, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Try below regex using grouping.

```
(?:<foo>)(.*?<\/foo>)
```

[regex101 online demo](http://regex101.com/r/uU9jY6/19)

Pictorial representation: [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OCExcNByWi9aj22r)

[image]

Sample code:

```
var re = /(?:<foo>)(.*?<\/foo>)/;
var str = 'hello <foo>remove me</foo>';
var subst = '<foo></foo>';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Output:

```
hello <foo></foo>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: choose one that is more efficient and solve the problem.  I don't know which one is more efficient.

Comment: Hmm `re = /(.*<foo>)(\w).*(<\/foo>)/gm;` is still repeating `foo` in closing tag.

Comment: sorry @anubhava I didn't get it. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: What I meant that your regex has `foo` keyword twice in it.

Comment: I don't mind the keyword appearing twice in the regex; I just didn't want it in the replacement string.

Comment: I think OP has updated the post. where is `r` that was in between `<foo>r</foo>`

Comment: That extra "r" was a typo that I since removed.  Sorry for the confusion.  (FWIW, pronoun is "her", not "his".)

Comment: +Braj, no problem.  As you see, I make typos too. :-)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not meant for criticism but just for academic purpose I clicked on your [regex demo link](http://regex101.com/r/uU9jY6/9) and then clicked `"regex debugger"` which took 59 steps. Then I clicked on my [regex demo link](http://regex101.com/r/uU9jY6/5) and clicked `"regex debugger"` that takes 23 steps to finish.

Comment: @anubhava I never noticed this link of regex101. Thanks next time I'll try to make it lower.

Comment: @anubhava I did it in 12 steps. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uU9jY6/10) just half of yours. :)

Comment: yes I have already noticed that thing. just forget to add `/` to close the foo tag. As edited it in my post as well,

Comment: It still matched `hello <foo>remove me</bar>` input

Comment: @anubhava yes it matches. Let me try to make it more optimize.

Comment: @anubhava Is this not the case with your regex that checks only for `</`

Comment: No my regex won't match it since I use back reference `<\/\1>` forcing to match same closing tag.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your time and sharing knowledge. I came till 28 steps in my latest update code.

Comment: You're welcome. It is my last comment before I sign off. Your latest regex is still replacing `<foo>remove me</bar>` which it shouldn't since open and close tags are different.

Comment: @anubhava finally I came to my first regex pattern and with some modification it comes to 24 steps.

Comment: @Braj: the only problem with your pattern is that it will fail with a string like `"<foo>abcdefg</foo><foo>hijklmno</foo>"` since it will match the entire string instead of `<foo>abcdefg</foo>` because the quantifier `*` is greedy. About, regex101 steps (or the regexbuddy steps): It is usefull to see how many steps are necessary to make your pattern succeed or fail. But keep in mind that this information is not always related to the real pattern performance. The only way to be sure is a timer.

Comment: @Braj: Yes, It will work if you make the quantifier lazy. But a lazy quantifier is slower than a greedy quantifier for long strings.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes now it takes 27 steps instead of 24 steps.

Comment: @Braj: perhaps, but you will not have false results.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for your inputs. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Braj: no problems, regexes are not easy. There are a lot of notions to master, in the order: character classes, greedy/lazy, backtracking, atomic/possessive, lookarounds, captures/backreferences/subpatterns/named patterns, recursions, backtracking control verbs...